# Python: Using __self__ instead of self as first argument of "instance method"

Tags: python

I recently came across this piece of code:

```
class InlineParameterResolver:
    def resolve(__self__, value: str) -> Any:
        return value
```

Now, I am aware that this code is strange as the class itself has no instance methods, nor an init method to enable it to create an instance and operate on its internal attributes, but does having the __self__ as the first argument have any special function/behaviour?

I have tried to google for an answer, but couldn't find anything, I just want to know if this is an opportunity to learn something, or if I'm just reading Python from someone who didn't have a lot of experience with the language.

Cheers.

Comment: Where did you find that code? What's the context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does having the `__self__` as the first argument have any special function/behaviour?

There is no special function or behavior. Even using `self` is just a naming convention for the first positional argument, using `foo` or anything else would work all the same.

However, using the name `__self__` is not advisable, because that already has  a different meaning in the [datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html): when an instance method object is created by retrieving a function object from a class via one of its instances, its `__self__` attribute is the instance, and the method object is said to be bound.

```
>>> class A:
...     def f(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.f.__self__
<__main__.A object at 0xdeadbeef>
```

Using double underscore names as function arguments is strange enough to cause confusion, so I'd recommend avoiding that.

Comment: Cheers for a concise response! So even in a "normal" object class with an init method and instance vars etc, using the term self to describe the object the instance method is defined for, is completely your choice?

Comment: Yep. It's just a convention (and similarly using `cls` instead of `self` for the first positional argument of classmethods). But virtually everybody follows this convention, so the readability will suffer if you don't follow it.

Comment: Righto, I had no idea, so in that case, does that mean that whenever a class is defined, the first positional argument to the method refers to the instance, except in cases where the method is defined as a @staticmethod? Sorry for digging in deeper here!

Comment: Almost - if it is decorated with `@classmethod` then the first positional argument is the _type_, not an _instance_. With `@staticmethod` there is no first positional argument implicitly passed, all arguments (if any) are passed explicitly. Note that `@staticmethod` isn't much used in Python, since it's usually better just to use a module level function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You described some code of uncertain provenance:

```
    def resolve(__self__, value):
```

Any of these would behave identically:

```
    def resolve(foo, value):

    def resolve(baz, value):

    def resolve(self, value):
```

Prefer the last one, as it is conventional.

We write code to communicate with the machine, yes.
But **primarily** we write so as to clearly communicate Author's Intent
to the reader.
In a python context, not using `self` (or `cls` for a classmethod)
is going to obscure the intent and leave the Gentle Reader scratching his head
in confusion. Go the conventional route.